# C++ usage of allocated memory inside structs

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, data-structures, struct

So, i was doing some harcker rank exercisies, and i found [this exercise](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/attending-workshops/problem).

In short it is an Interval Schedulling problem, but my doubt is about pointers and data structure.

This code below is a simple version of my doubt.

My doubt is in the **initialize** function. When the program finishes it the **ptr** pointer variable has only one instance of **arrayOfA**, the first entry only and i wanted to have the size of N.

So what i did get wrong about this data structure and it`s pointers?

I don't want to use another lib as vector and stuff because i think there is no need of it.

```
#include <iostream>
 
struct A
{
    unsigned int startTime;
    unsigned int duration;
    unsigned int endTime;
};
 
struct B
{
    int size;
    A* arrayOfA = new A[size];
};
 
B* initialize(int start_time[], int duration[], int n)
{
    B* pointer = new B();
 
    pointer->size = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pointer->arrayOfA[i].startTime = start_time[i];
        pointer->arrayOfA[i].duration = duration[i];
        pointer->arrayOfA[i].endTime = start_time[i] + duration[i];
    }
 
    return pointer;
}
 
int main()
{
    //initialization
    int n = 6;
    int arrayOfStart[] = { 1, 3, 0, 5, 5, 8 };
    int arrayOfDuration[] = { 1, 1, 6, 2, 4, 1 };
    
    B* ptr;
    ptr = initialize(arrayOfStart, arrayOfDuration, n);
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << ptr->arrayOfA[i].startTime << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: `A* arrayOfA = new A[size];` invokes *undefined behavior* as `size` is not initialized by the time this executes

Comment: *I don't want to use another lib as vector and stuff because i think there is no need of it.* -- I guess memory leaks are ok?  Your program leaks memory in several places.

Comment: If this were an academic exercise to learn how things like `std::vector` are implemented it would be justified. But otherwise it's generally best to use the standard library, it works well.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to use another lib as vector and stuff because i think there is no need of it

The fact that you got this simple example wrong - and that this simple example is actually not that simple to implement correctly - is solid evidence that *you are wrong*.

The whole point of having standard libraries is that there is rarely a good reason to implement these things by hand, and it's easy to get them wrong. And `std::vector` is not "another lib", it is provided by the standard library for a reason.

> the ptr pointer variable has only one instance of arrayOfA

it's only supposed to have one array. You mean, presumably, that the array is the wrong size? How did you tell? What happened when you tried to read all 6 elements?

Anyway, the immediate problem is

```
A* arrayOfA = new A[size];
```

... this should go in a constructor. You have to defer evaluation until *after* you know the value of `size`.

Then you should also write a destructor, and then you should write the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, and move equivalents.

But if you learned, and used, `std::vector` instead - you would have finished the problem in the time it took to debug your array handling code.

The whole point of providing libraries of common tools is that you can learn them once and re-use your knowledge. If you write your own bare array code in every hackerrank problem, you can easily encounter *different* bugs in each one, and you're not accumulating any knowledge you can re-use in the next.

Comment: Thanks, i've seen the rookie mistake that i made.

About the std::vector, i did not want to use it because the program receive from the user the size of the array and it's not needed to resize or push_back and stuff in this particular exercise.

Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Given this struct:

```
struct B
{
    int size;
    A* arrayOfA = new A[size];
};
```

a default `B` will have a pointer pointing to an array of `size` elements. Since `size` is not initialized, this invokes undefined behavior.

Instead, you can do:

```
struct B
{
    int size;
    A* arrayOfA;
};
```

and after you set the `size` member, you can allocate the appropriate memory:

```
pointer->size = n;
pointer->arrayOfA = new A[pointer->size];
```

Also, don't forget to delete this memory when it's no longer needed by the program.

Comment: Addendum: Remember that a `struct` can have constructors, so you can easily make sure that the act of getting a `B` forces correct initialization of the `B`.